# Using Clojure deftype as a parameterized function

Tags: clojure, deftype

I am trying to use clojure in a compiler and thus need to parameterize calls to `deftype`; however, I am having difficulty making the type hints carry through.  Consider the following code:

```
(defn describe [x] 
  (let [fields (.getDeclaredFields x)
        names (map #(.getName %) fields)
        types (map #(.getType %) fields)]
    (interleave types names)))

(defn direct [] (deftype direct-type [^int x]))
(defn indirect-helper [] (list ^int (symbol "x")))
(defn indirect [] (eval `(deftype ~(symbol  "indirect-type") ~(indirect-helper))))
```

And the following session from the REPL:

```
Clojure 1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
1:1 user=> #<Namespace dataclass>
1:2 dataclass=> (direct)
dataclass.direct-type
1:3 dataclass=> (indirect)
dataclass.indirect-type
1:4 dataclass=> (describe direct-type)
(int "x")
1:5 dataclass=> (describe indirect-type)
(java.lang.Object "x")
```

Notice that the generated class for indirect-type has lost the ^int hints that direct-type has.  How do I get those hints to carry through?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to change `indirect-helper` to read

```
(defn indirect-helper [] [(with-meta (symbol "x") {:tag 'int})])
```

The reason is that `^int` parses as `^` followed by `int`; `^`, in Clojure 1.2, introduces reader metadata (in 1.1 you'd use `#^`, which still works, but is deprecated in 1.2). Thus `^int x` in `direct` gets *read in* as a `clojure.lang.Symbol` whose name is `"x"` and whose metadata map is `{:tag int}` (with the `int` here being itself a symbol). (The final component of a symbol -- its namespace -- is `nil` in this case.)

In the version of `indirect-helper` from the question text `^int` gets attached to `(symbol "x")` -- the list comprising the symbol `symbol` and the string `"x"` (meaning in particular that `(list ^int (symbol "x"))` evaluates to a list of 1 element). This "type hint" is lost once `(symbol "x")` is evaluated. To fix things, some way to attach metadata to the actual symbol generated by `(symbol "x")` is needed.

Now in this case, the symbol is generated at runtime, so you can't use reader metadata to attach the type hint to it. Enter `with-meta`, which attaches metadata at runtime (and is frequently useful in writing macros for the same reason as it is here) and the day is saved:

```
user> (indirect)
user.indirect-type
user> (describe indirect-type)
(int "x")
```

(BTW, I thought `deftype` expected a vector of field names, but apparently a list works as well... A vector is still certainly more idiomatic.)